# How can I fix an invalid syntax error in my code?

Tags: python

so I've been trying to run this code but I keep getting a syntax error. It's on the part where I try to use previous variables to convert them into another coordinate system. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
import time as t
import datetime 
import math as m

start_time = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 0, 0).timestamp() 

print("This code gives the coordinates in xyz and Latitude and Longitude")
time_now = t.time() 
time_between = time_now - start_time
x = 5978.43 * m.cos(0.00129 * (time_between - 24066))
y = 4134.68 * m.cos(0.00129 * (time_between - 20190))
z = -4836.3 * m.cos(0.00129 * (time_between - 20581))
r = m.sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2) #I get the error here
theta = m.acos(z/r)
phi = m.atan(y/x)
latitude = (theta*180/m.pi - 90)* -1
print("The coordinates are:\n", "x = ", round(x, 2),"\n", "y = ", round(y, 2),"\n", "z = ", round(z, 2))
print("The latitude is: ", latitude, "and the Longitude is: ", phi)
```

Comment: Well... Post your syntax error then ;)

Comment: you're missing a bracket on that line..

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close `m.sqrt` as below:

```
import time as t
import datetime 
import math as m

start_time = datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 13, 0, 0).timestamp() 

print("This code gives the coordinates in xyz and Latitude and Longitude")
time_now = t.time() 
time_between = time_now - start_time
x = 5978.43 * m.cos(0.00129 * (time_between - 24066))
y = 4134.68 * m.cos(0.00129 * (time_between - 20190))
z = -4836.3 * m.cos(0.00129 * (time_between - 20581))
r = m.sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2) + pow(z, 2)) #I get the error here
theta = m.acos(z/r)
phi = m.atan(y/x)
latitude = (theta*180/m.pi - 90)* -1
print("The coordinates are:\n", "x = ", round(x, 2),"\n", "y = ", round(y, 2),"\n", "z = ", round(z, 2))
print("The latitude is: ", latitude, "and the Longitude is: ", phi)
```